# Python dataframe : converting columns into rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows

```
d = {'Movie' : ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather'],
        'FirstName1': ['Tim', 'Marlon'],
        'FirstName2': ['Morgan', 'Al'],
        'LastName1': ['Robbins', 'Brando'],
        'LastName2': ['Freeman', 'Pacino'],
        'ID1': ['TM', 'MB'],
        'ID2': ['MF', 'AP']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

[image]

I would like to re-arrange it into a 4 column dataframe,
by converting `Firstname1, LastName1, FirstName2, LastName2, ID1, ID2` into 3 column rows as `FirstName, LastName, ID` then column `movie` repeats as follows.
[image]

In `sql` we do it as follows

```
select Movie as Movie, FirstName1 as FirstName, LastName1 as LastName, ID1 as ID from table
union
select Movie as Movie, FirstName2 as FirstName, LastName2 as LastName, ID2 as ID from table
```

Can we achieve it using pandas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible number in column names more like `9` use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get integers with values before to `MultiIndex` to columns, so possible [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Movie')
df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1[0], df1[1].astype(int)])

df = df.rename_axis((None, None), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
                      Movie FirstName  ID LastName
0  The Shawshank Redemption       Tim  TM  Robbins
1  The Shawshank Redemption    Morgan  MF  Freeman
2             The Godfather    Marlon  MB   Brando
3             The Godfather        Al  AP   Pacino
```

If not use indexing for get last values of columns names with all previous and pass to [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Movie')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.str[:-1], df.columns.str[-1].astype(int)])
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
                      Movie FirstName  ID LastName
0  The Shawshank Redemption       Tim  TM  Robbins
1  The Shawshank Redemption    Morgan  MF  Freeman
2             The Godfather    Marlon  MB   Brando
3             The Godfather        Al  AP   Pacino
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.set_index('Movie')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col[:-1], col[-1:]) for col in df.columns])

df.stack()

#                           FirstName  ID LastName
#Movie                                            
#The Shawshank Redemption 1       Tim  TM  Robbins
#                         2    Morgan  MF  Freeman
#The Godfather            1    Marlon  MB   Brando
#                         2        Al  AP   Pacino
```

Use the power of MultiIndex! With [`from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) you create a `DataFrame` that has one column for FirstNames, divided in FirstName1 and FirstName2 (see below) and similar for ID and LastName. With [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) you convert it into rows for each. Before you do this, make `Movie` the Index to exclude it from what you are doing. You could use [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to regain everything as columns, but I'm not sure if you want that.

---

Before `stack`:

```
#                         FirstName         LastName           ID    
#                                 1       2        1        2   1   2
#Movie                                                               
#The Shawshank Redemption       Tim  Morgan  Robbins  Freeman  TM  MF
#The Godfather               Marlon      Al   Brando   Pacino  MB  AP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to do this is to use the copy function from Pandas. 
You can copy the columns "Movie", "FirstName", "LastName", "ID" to a new table. Then delete the columns you don't need in your first column. You can also create a new table for the other.

```
new = d['Movie', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ID].copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
d1 = df.filter(regex="1$|Movie").rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1])
d2 = df.filter(regex="2$|Movie").rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1])
pd.concat([d1, d2]).rename({'Movi':'Movie'})
```